# Whats the meaning of the % symbol in a data declaration?

Tags: abap

I found this data declaration in ABAP code. Does anyone know what this `%` means?

```
Data: %rlmob type str_mob
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing more than any other character, outside of ABAP Objects (["The name must start with a letter or an underscore (_). Only outside of ABAP objects can the name also start with a different character."](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abennaming_conventions.htm)). It's recommended to use ABAP objects, so % is deprecated. Historically it's also often used by SAP for naming "system" (i.e. very low-level SAP programs) variables, types, and any other kind of symbols.

Comment: The `%` at the start is a benign example! Outside of ABAP Objects, far worse identifiers are allowed, like a structure named `&#3_` that has a component named `----`.